# Call file using AJAX from a file called from JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to call the server side from a file called trough `JQuery`. This is so hard to explain but what I am really doing is, I call a file that will pop up like a window using `JQuery`. Then in that pop up window I am going to call the server side file using an `AJAX`.

This is how I called the first file:

**JQUERY**

```
function AddBill(id) {
    $("#displayDIV").show();
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("displayDIV").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","file1.php?",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now I want to call another file inside the `file1.php`

**AJAX**

```
$(function() { 
    $("#formAdd").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert();
        $.ajax({  
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: "post",  
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            error:function(){
                alert("ERROR : CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

By the way. This is where I call the `AddBill()`

```
<input type="button" class="updateButton" value="ADD BILLED TO" onclick="AddBill()"/>
```

And this is the content of my `file1.php`

```
<form id="formAdd" action="server.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD">
</form>
```

The **AJAX** is not being read by the program. Where did I go wrong or what is the better way to do this?

THANKS

Comment: you may need to wrap the ajax in a `script` tag, so the contents are interpreted as a script by the browser

Comment: yes. I did that. My jQuery and Ajax are both in the same script tag.

Comment: They are both in the same script tag?? Like `<script src="path_to_jQuery"> function(){...}</script>` If so, try your script in another script tag. You can't include scripts in a script tag that has a `src` attribute.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette so I put another script tag inside the html or should I put it inside the file I called?

Comment: Do you want the AJAX to execute after it finishes loading on this line: `document.getElementById("displayDIV").innerHTML = this.responseText;`  ?

Comment: You need a script tag to call the library `<script src="path_to_jQuery"></script>`. Then another script tag for your script `<script> function(){...}</script>`

Comment: @Filype no. I have a button inside the `file1.php` that will call the AJAX. I will add it in my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the updated question, perhaps your ajax code is running before the contents are added on the page:

Try this in your ajax:

```
$(document).on('submit', "#formAdd", function(e) {
```

instead of

```
$("#formAdd").submit(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not execute scripts that are inserted in the DOM. You should consider other ways of achieving this.

You can include a script, adn then inject the contents of `file1.php` as an exmaple:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var g = document.createElement('script');
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.text = this.responseText;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}
```

There are some other useful solutions on this question: [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)